# submitting a form returns drrectory listing

Tags: vb.net

I have a form on a page:

```
<form name="addLeader2" action="Add_FFYouthMinistryLeaders.aspx" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="AdultFF" id="AdultFF" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="CatechesisEarly_PreK" id="CatechesisEarly_PreK" /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="CatechesisGradeK_5_6" id="CatechesisGradeK_5_6" /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="CatechesisGrade6_7_HS" id="CatechesisGrade6_7_HS" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="OtherComponents" id="OtherComponents" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="SacPrep_FirstPen_FirstCom" id="SacPrep_FirstPen_FirstCom" /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="SacPrep_Confirm" id="SacPrep_Confirm" /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="Other" id="Other" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="OtherSpecify" id="OtherSpecify" value="" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="FFYMID" id="Hidden1" value="" /><br />
   </form>
```

When the form is submitted, the browser displays a directory listing rather than following the contents of the processing page and redirecting back to the page with the form on it. I know the processing page executed as the database was modified and a new record entered. I then tried creating a new processing page and pointing to it, but it still gives me a directory listing rather than loading. By the way, the new page I created was completely blank, just to see if the page would load. I'm running Visual Studio 2012, if that helps.

What would cause the directory listing?

Comment: Are you using web forms? Also, you know Visual Studio 2019 is free, right? 2012 is seriously out of date.

Comment: Also, you see a directory listing if the IIS web server has that option enabled and it is also not configured to process the requested file type in another way.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that VS 2019 is free. I am downloading it as I type my response. In response to IIS, I'm not running IIS, I'm testing my code with the built in Server from Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the code and found the issue. The page is a web forms page built with VB.net

After scouring the code for an hour, I determined that the placement of runat="server" which resides in the form element had to move to a new form tag at the top of the page contents. This was due to the html form element not properly receiving the action attribute once the form ran on the server.

Once the page contents were wrapped in
`<form runat="server"></form>`, the other form I was submitting, opened the processing page and everything now functions as expected.

Comment: If you're using web forms, there's **ONE** special html form on the page and you should not add any other forms. Usually this special form encloses the entire contents of the page.